# Autoloading Namespaced Classes

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, autoload

I have searched high and low for an answer and tried every example, but this still fails to find my classes. Why do I keep getting **Fatal error:** Class 'ProjectMorpheus\model\Database' not found in C:\Portables\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMorpheus\config\config.php on line 23

```
/ProjectMorpheus
  /model
    Database.class.php
  /config
    config.php
```

So my Database class has a namespace  like this:

```
namespace ProjectMorpheus\model;
class Database { ... }
```

Finally, my config.php has a function autoloader function (Note: __SITE_PATH = 'C:\Portables\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMorpheus\'):

```
/*** auto load model classes ***/
function __autoload($class){
  $parts = explode('\\', $class);
  include __SITE_PATH . 'model/' . end($parts) . '.class.php';
}

$dbh = \ProjectMorpheus\model\Database::getInstance($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Using spl_autoloader appears to work, but why? My only guess is that $class is not the same in both instances. My spl_function looks like:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
   $parts = explode('\\', $class);
   include __SITE_PATH . 'model/' . end($parts) . '.class.php';
});
```

Comment: __SITE_PATH here smells a rat... can you print it to see its content? Aslo, remove the first slash before  \ProjectMorpheus\model\Database::getInstance($dsn, $username, $password);

Comment: I would recommend using `spl_autoload_register()`,  more info can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: @GRSEV You are correct, I have updated my question.  I can 100% confirm that __SITE_PATH === C:\Portables\xampp\htdocs\ProjectMorpheus\ and removing the first / during class declaration does not fix the problem.

Comment: @cmorrissey I agree with you; however, the server I am being forced to use doesn't have a PHP version that supports spl_autoload

Comment: spl_autoload  is from PHP 5.1.2 , NAMESPACES - form 5.3. If you dont have 'spl_autoload' then you may not have NAMESPACE support aslo... what is your PHP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [**PSR-0**](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) or **PSR-4** autoloader standards?

They even have ready-to-use autoloader class on [**GitHub**](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634) As long as you will follow the rules, you won't have any issues and your code will be PSR.

Although I wouldn't recommend but if you would like to insist using the code above for autoloading classes (only in models folder) then try to dump what is the value of `__SITE_PATH . 'model/' . end($parts) . '.class.php';` and check if you can access it. You can even try to copy and paste the path to your file explorer to see if the location is reachable and file exists in that directory.

P.S. I tried to add this as a comment but I couldn't due to low rep. points (being new around here and all).

Comment: I did as you said and echoed __SITE_PATH . 'model/' . end($parts) . '.class.php'; out and then copied and pasted it to file explorer.  It works fine.

Comment: I guess my new question would be why does __autoload fail to execute the same function as spl_autoload.  My only guess is that $class is different, but I am unable to echo out what $class is within the __autoload function.

Comment: As long as your path and file name is accessible you shouldn't have problem with it. Try to output the variables in both and see what is the actual difference right before including the class file. By the way if PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoloader fixes the problem it is better to stick with standards. You will be finding more and more other PHP classes / libraries in PSR standards which means it would be a lot easier for you to use them in your projects.